# How to reuse a view without reinflating it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a linear layout with ListView inside it. I inflated a TextView and added it at 0 position of linear layout, How to remove this view from its parent and add as ListView header at run-time without re-inflating it?

Comment: remove it and again add as a header? Please be more clear.

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks for your reply. If I do that I am getting this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams" any idea why?